# /usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using `git bash` on Windows. I want to run `ls` command with `bash`. I can run `ls` separately like this:

```
$ ls
f1  f2
```

However, when I try with `bash`, I get the error:

```
$ bash ls
/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

But if I create my script it works fine:

```
$ echo "echo \$@" > my.sh && bash my.sh
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: `bash -c ls`. From the manpage: _If the -c option is present, then commands are read from  the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after the command_string,  they  are  assigned  to  the positional parameters, starting with $0._

Comment: @ridgy, thanks, it works this way. I'm not very proficient with bash yet. Can you please post an elaborate answer and explain why it works with my custom script without `-c` option and why it's needed for `ls`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the fine manual for [`bash(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> ARGUMENTS
>          If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the -c nor the
>          -s  option  has  been supplied, **the first argument is assumed to be the
>          name of a file** containing shell commands.

Does `ls` contain shell commands? No, it is a binary file. `bash` squawks about this fact and fails.

A `strace` may help show what is going on:

```
$ strace -o alog bash ls
/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

The `alog` file can get a bit messy, but shows `bash` looking for `ls` in the current working directory—a security risk if someone has placed a naughty `ls` file somewhere!—and then does a `PATH` search:

```
$ grep ls alog
execve("/usr/bin/bash", ["bash", "ls"], [/* 43 vars */]) = 0
open("ls", O_RDONLY)                    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/ls", 0x7fff349810f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=117672, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=117672, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/ls", X_OK)             = 0
stat("/usr/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=117672, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/ls", R_OK)             = 0
stat("/usr/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=117672, ...}) = 0
stat("/usr/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=117672, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/ls", X_OK)             = 0
stat("/usr/bin/ls", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=117672, ...}) = 0
access("/usr/bin/ls", R_OK)             = 0
open("/usr/bin/ls", O_RDONLY)           = 3
```

As to why this could be a security risk, if you run `bash somecmd` from the wrong directory where someone has created a `ls` (or some other known command due to a bug in a script):

```
$ echo "echo rm -rf /" > ls
$ bash ls
rm -rf /
$
```

Comment: thanks, can you elaborate a bit on this _If arguments remain after option processing_? An example maybe?

Comment: @Maximus your `bash ls` is an example of an argument that remains, as `bash` tried to read it as if it were a file of shell commands.

Comment: yeah, I understood that. _If arguments remain after option processing_ - what option processing? `bash -c -s` - these?

Comment: @Maximus yes, those are options. Some consume additional arguments.